# Wordpress TinyMCE editor turns white on Biographical info

Tags: tinymce, wordpress

I tried out the solution found here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33552/how-to-use-tinymce-for-user-biographical-info-without-messing-with-any-core-fi/33575#33575 and added it to my plugin code.

The problem is, it turns the editor white
 [image]

How do I make it show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to use this plugin instead:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/visual-biography-editor/

It will make the description textarea get the same editor as the wordpress post/page editor.

Hope this helps anyone who passes by!

John